# Euler rotations and acceleration

Tags: mechanical-engineering, kinematics, acceleration

I have a system determined by 3 Euler angles that describe the orientation with respect to a fixed coordinate system XYZ.

The angular velocities are: $\omega_2$ (precession), $\omega_1$ (nutation) and $\omega_z$ (spin).
The angular acceleration of $\omega_z$ is $\alpha_z$. The other angular accelerations are 0.

How can I find the acceleration of a point (e.g. A on the spinning reference frame xyz)?
I am looking for the procedure to follow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to be about which reference frame you are estimating the acceleration of A. I assume you need the accelation of A wrt to the inertial frame of reference.

The most generic way is to link the acceleration of A to B. Then find the acceleration of B with respect to O.

See the following [link  for a starting point](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec25.pdf)

The bottom line is that if you need the acceleration of P with respect to O, then you'll probably just need the following two equations:

$$\vec{v}_P =\vec{v}_O + \vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}_P$$
$$\vec{a}_P =\vec{a}_O + \dot{\vec{\omega}}\times \vec{r}_P + \vec{\omega}\times \left( \vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}_P\right)$$

Comment: I need it indeed wrt the initial reference frame. This was the confirmation. I needed. Thanks.